SPF - How does it really work?
While investigating DMARC reports I realised I do not really understand some aspects of email. I am trying to make sure I have concepts related to SPF and DMARC correct.
If an eMail message passes through several intermediate nodes...

Each connection between servers passes on an envelope "MAIL FROM:" value established during the initial SMTP handshake by the sender's MUA. The value of the "MAIL FROM:" does not change as the message travels through the network. The final MTA may add a "Return-Path:" header based on the "MAIL FROM:".
The "<header_from>" element in DMARC reports is based on the message's "From:" header, which is set by the sender's client.
The final MTA in the chain implements the SPF and DMARC checks. SPF checks the source IP address of the node connecting to it. Not the originating source IP address.
Intermediate nodes do not perform SPF checking. They primarily relay the email without altering the envelope information.
Given point three, my DNS's SPF TXT record must include the IP address of every possible intermediate node that could connect directly to the recipient's MTA.

So, since intermediate nodes play no part in SPF. If I could ensure fake eMails were injected mid chain; before the node making the connection to the final MTA. So SPF would pass? It should also be possible to fake the "MAIL FROM:" and "From:"; so DMARC would pass as well?
Is the above correct or are there any other points I have missed?

https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/

You have fundamental misconceptions on how email works. There are not any "intermediate" servers that operate like post offices, but in a typical setup one (sending) email infrastructure delivers the message to another (receiving infrastructure). The SPF check should happen on the edge of those infrastructures directly against the connection; not the former Received headers that can be forged.
DKIM signature on the other hand stays valid as long as the signed content does not change and, therefore, can be checked as close to the final destination as desired. DMARC does not authenticate the message but enforces the authentication provided by SPF or DKIM, requiring alignment with the hostname used in the From header.
Forwarding and mailing list scenarios are bit more complicated. As a properly configured SPF would not pass after forwarding, the forwarding infrastructure should rewrite the envelope sender. The SPF check per se will pass, but the SPF+DMARC alignment gets broken. Hence, forwarding relies entirely on DKIM+DMARC, and mailing lists should either avoid modifying the message contents or rewrite the From header and re-sign the message with their own DKIM key.
